# How can I find the analog output of a color sensor?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, ev3, programming

Could anyone provide me with an image of the voltage output of an NXT or EV3 colorsensor. 
I would like to have the analog output if it's possible, and not  the digital output.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what programming software you are using.  The education versions of the NXT and EV3 software having data logging features that may be what you are looking for.

The education versions of NXT and EV3 programming software are available for purchase from www.education.lego.com

Comment: I do have the Education set.. 
Could you guide me on how to find the output?
I own both, but EV3 would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption here that by analog, you mean something more fine-grained than just the 6 or 7 colors.

Both the NXT and EV3 color sensors have the capability of reading the individual color components. The value read is not a voltage, but just a "percent" of reflected light of each color.

<strike>For NXT-G, you can find a block [here](http://www.teamhassenplug.org/NXT/NXTGAdditions.html) (the *Color Range Block*).</strike> (see comments)

For EV3-G you can find a block [here](http://mindcuber.com/mindcub3r/mindcub3r.html#ColorSensorRGBBlock). The EV3 block requires firmware version 1.06 (there is a bug that prevents it working in earlier versions).

Comment: Sorry to break it to you, but the block you linked to for NXT-G doesn't work. If you try to import it via the block import and export wizard, it won't import. The author of the block even acknowledged this and apologized, and said that he probably wouldn't fix it since he has way to many different versions of things on his computer. I would cite my source on where he said this, but that forum seems to have recently gone down...